# Proxmox hyper-convergence and storage redundancy

Tags: storage, proxmox, redundancy

What kind of storage redundancy (data blocks at least on two different physical machines) does [Proxmox Hyper-Convergence](https://pve.proxmox.com/wiki/Hyper-converged_Infrastructure) provide? Nutanix does it with [a controller VM (CVM)](http://next.nutanix.com/t5/How-It-Works/CVM/td-p/12526#messageBodySimpleDisplay_0), VxRail with [VMware vSAN](https://www.vmware.com/products/vsan.html) and SimpliVity with [an I/O card (OVC)](https://www.google.com/search?q=OmniStack+Virtual+Controller).